# unity-CardboardDesignLab,add distortion-unity,but the ui is running in iphone is upside down

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I try to run the samples/CardboardDesignLab/ustwo-cardboard-unity demo.
I just checked distortionCorrection-unity
Put it into the apk，it is running normally in android devices.
but ,the same code, build and run in iphone is upside down,I only changed the distortionCorrection.
Please Help me,thanks very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that plugin is absolute. You should now be using [Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started-android) instead of google-cardboard.

If you are still reluctant to use the [Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started-android), then find `BaseCardboardDevice.cs` script in the plugin, then find a function inside it called `UpdateState()`.

Add `headPose.Set(headPose.Position, headPose.Orientation * Quaternion.Euler(0,0,180));` to the end of that function. That's it. It will rotate the Camera back to 180 which make it look normal again.